# complex sql join between 2 tables

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am developing in php a system of store points.

I have two tables:

**store_points**

- id_store_point
- store_point_name

**book_tranfers**

- id_tranfer
- from_store_point_id
- to_store_point_id
- date_of_transfer
- quantity_of_books

I would like to write some sql code in order to display in the same line both the name of the store_point from which the books are coming and the name of the store_point where the books have been transfered.

Any help??
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I hope you don't have a feeling that SO will resolve your work without putting any effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T.*, S1.STORE_POINT_NAME AS FROM_STORE, S2.STORE_POINT_NAME AS TO_STORE
FROM BOOK_TRANSFERS T
JOIN STORE_POINTS S1 ON T.FROM_STORE_POINT_ID = S1.ID_STORE_POINT
JOIN STORE_POINTS S2 ON T.TO_STORE_POINT_ID = S2.ID_STORE_POINT
```